# Using Spring Cloud Gateway Server MVC for routing

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-11, spring-cloud-gateway

I am designing application using Spring boot, Spring Cloud Gateway Server MVC, thymeleaf , Java 11, Maven but I am new to Spring Cloud Gateway

My Spring application contains following dependencies

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.17</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.82</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-afterburner</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

GatewayConfiguration .java

```
package com.commonapplication.controller;

  import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
  import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
  import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
  @Configuration
  public class GatewayConfiguration {

    @Bean

    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes().
                route("example_route",r->r
                                                .path("/demo1/**")
                                                .uri("http://localhost:8090/demo1Service1"))
                .build();

       
    }
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping= TRACE
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

CommonApplication.java

```
package com.commonapplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CommonApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommonApplication.class, args);
        
    }
}
```

StartUpController.java

```
package com.commonapplication.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@Controller

public class StartUpController {
    
     @RequestMapping(value="/index",method=RequestMethod.GET) 
     public String index() {
         return "index";
     }

}
```

Code contains index.html file inside src->resources->template.
When "localhost:8080/index" is hit from browser. index.html is loaded propertly. This UI contains one button. On click of this button my application hits "localhost:8080/demo1/service1". Route is defined for path "demo1/**" in GatewayConfiguration.java file to map to application running on localhost:8090.
Code for mapped application running localhost:8090 is

application.properties

```
server.port=8090
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.demo1</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.82</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
        

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Demo1Application.java

```
package com.example.demo1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Demo1Controller.java

```
package com.example.demo1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController

public class Demo1Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value="/demo1Index",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap map) {
        return "demo1Index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/demo1Service1",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String demoS1() {
        System.out.println("Demo 1 is working.");
        return "demo1 is working";
    }

}
```

On hitting button I get following lines in log :

```
2023-11-24 13:45:45.223 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8080/demo1/service1?_=1700813739548] to Route{id='example_route', uri=http://localhost:8090/demo1Service1, order=0, predicate=Paths: [/demo1/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[], metadata={}}
2023-11-24 13:45:45.223 DEBUG 12936 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : [19d35c9c] Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler@23adefa8
2023-11-24 13:45:45.827 DEBUG 12936 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [19d35c9c] Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

I am not able to understand why my service running on 8090 is not found by my gateway. I have referred to many examples but each example contains use of eureka server. I am new to Spring Cloud Gateway, so I am not sure if this application will work without eureka server or not. Also, here I am using Spring Cloud Gateway Server MVC instead of Spring Cloud Gateway

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake after debugging in Spring-cloud-gateway-server jar.
Changed path in GatewayConfiguration.java to .path("/demo1Service") and changed uri to .uri("http://localhost:8090"). Now when I hit url htt://localhost:8080/demo1Service , it is successfully routed to http://localhost:8090/demo1Service.